# BadValueError when updating ndb entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am implementing a web application based on Google App Engine, Relying on ndb. I am facing a strange problem when trying to update one of the many entities in my db. When I try to update one of its properties (i.e. a string property) I get

```
&quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py&quot;, line 1715, in _validate (value,)) BadValueError: Expected string, got (u'a test',)
```

The same code works when I create a new entity of the same kind.

I know there will be soon someone asking me to add relevant code. It would be practically unreasonable to copy the javascript and python code I developed. I am interested to know if this behavior is known to occur in certain conditions I can check.

**UPDATE**

consider that the value with which I am trying to update the property is a post parameter (i.e. `self.request.get('parameter')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to assign a `tuple` to a model's ndb.StringProperty().

Comment: it is a  post parameter I am getting from the request

Comment: @lowcoupling -- Can you check to make sure that it isn't coming in as a `tuple`?  Without seeing your code, we can't do much more than guess...

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Find the line (in your code) (not ndb) where the exception is being raised and log the value just before you set it...

Comment: Ok I have logged it and checked in the Log Console of Google App Engine. I see the string I expected.

Comment: WOW I copied the code from the Entity creation where each property is separated by a comma. I didn't notice the comma remained at the end o the line ! You may want to update your answer

Comment: So there you have it.  It was a tuple ;-)